# How to align two widgets more closely in PyQt5 layouts?

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

How to align two widgets more closely? In my code, I want to align QLabel 1 and QLabel 2 more closely (i.e. QLabel 2 aligned just below the QLabel 1, with minimum spacing).

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets

class Layout_sample(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(). __init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Layout Sample")
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("F3")
        self.lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(u'\u2550'+u'\u2550')

        self.vbox.addStretch()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lbl1)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lbl2)
        self.vbox.addStretch()

        self.vbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)


if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = Layout_sample()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume what you're trying to achieve is a double underline for the text in the first label. The problem with your example is that the unicode character `═` (U+2550) is centered vertically, so there will always be some fixed space above it. The unicode [box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) don't include a top-aligned double-underline, so a different approach is needed.

One solution is to use html/css inside the label to draw a double border below the text. This has to be done using a table-cell, because Qt only supports a [limited subset of html/css](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html):

```
    underline = """<td style="
        border-bottom-style: double;
        border-bottom-width: 3px;
        ">%s</td>"""
    self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(underline % 'F3')
    self.vbox.addStretch()
    self.vbox.addWidget(self.lbl1)
    self.vbox.addStretch()
```

[image]